# Get users that made order every month from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions

This is my database table: `orders`

| id | user_id | order_id | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1245652 | 1607444387 |
| 2 | 2 | 3265784 | 1607357987 |
| 3 | 1 | 9521014 | 1607357927 |
| 4 | 3 | 1036951 | 1607317987 |

I want to have a list of users that place at least one order every month. how i can do that?

Comment: Why is this tagged with jquery?

Comment: Le'ts say now is August? So you want data for months of Jan to Aug this year?

Comment: @WillardSolutions by mistake, i want to tag query. fixed. thank you

Comment: Every month in what time period?

Comment: @wpanchev i want get list of users that diffrence time between their orders less than 30 days

Comment: @GordonLinoff in 2 years ago

Comment: You should have written that to your question at the first place, so you're gettting the wrong answers, and it got you a downvote, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select user_id
from orders o
where datetime >= :from and datetime < :to
group by user_id
having count(distinct extract(year_month from from_unixtime(datetime))) = :num_months
```

`:from`, `:to`, and `:num_months` indicate parameters.  The first two define the date range you want.  The third indicates the number of months that constitute "every month" in the time frame.

Comment: thank you, i think there is some issue in query and when i run query, i get syntax error
i correct query to this:

    select user_id
from orders t
where datetime >= :from and `datetime` < :to
group by user_id
having count(distinct extract(year_month from (FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)))) = :num_month

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the number of month per user to the total count of months in the table like so:

```
select user_id
from mytable t
group by user_id
having count(distinct date_format(from_unixtime(datetime), '%Y-%m-01')) 
    = (select timestampdiff(month, min(datetime), max(datetime)) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function `count` as follows:

```
Select distinct user_id from
(Select user_id,
       Count(distinct extract(year_month from_unixtime(datetime))
             over () as total_months,
       Count(distinct extract(year_month from_unixtime(datetime)) 
             over (partition by user_id) as user_all_months
  From your_table) t
Where user_all_months = total_months;
```